# Interface "React\Promise\ExtendedPromiseInterface" not found

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, composer

So I upgraded the page from Craft 2.9 to latest 3.x.x version.

Now I am trying to install a plugin and I get this error - any help?
[image]

Cheers